# Unable to run my Angularjs code in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have write AngularJs code first time in jsFiddle and unable to run code.

HTML code:-

```
<div ng-app="eshopApp" ng-controller="checkoutCtrl">
  <button ng-click="testTask()">Test</button>
</div>
```

js code:-

```
var eshopApp = angular.module('eshopApp', []);

   eshopApp.controller('checkoutCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

     $scope.testTask=function(){
      alert('working');
  }
});
```

Please find jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/clsah/onbg6y6a/

Comment: Change the code location to `No Wrap - In <head>` - http://jsfiddle.net/6m9hw00n/

Comment: a lot of thanks for quick solved answer. @RGraham

Comment: @CLSah, or better use [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/) - much much better

Comment: Or use ... `StackOverflow` and put code into code snippet witch `ctrl + m` when you answer